# Woocommerce custom category pages

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I am searching for the best solution to create custom category pages in woocommerce.

I started off with using the standard category pages of woocommerce and put some html in the textbox which was quite ok, but as I needed some more styling I went for the enhanced category pages plugin. There you can edit the category page with visual composer and style everything quite nicely. Problem is that yoast plugin doesn't show up there so you can't work with some proper seo.

After that I thought it would be the best way to just create own pages for my categories as they won't change to often and load the products via shortcodes. That works really well and gives me all the control over the category pages I need, but I didn't have in mind that the menu won't be active when I click on a product as I don't use the woocommerce category pages, but my custom wordpress pages.

Anybody know a nice solution for this? In an ideal world I would like the system to recognize my custom category pages and make the menu active when I take a look at a product in this category. Other way would be to be able to out title and description in the enhanced category plugins pages.

I hope I could describe my problem quite good and somebody can help me out, thanks!

Comment: The pages on this website have a specific design. The customer wants to have this design in his category pages too. As visual composer was used to build this layout and functionality I need to use it on the category pages, too. Therefore I tried two things: I installed a plugin so that I can use VC in the category (enhanced category pages) but some features of it are not loaded (_wpb_shortcodes_custom_css?) so it looks totally different.

Comment: The other thing I tried is to create simple pages, layout them the way I want and load the products by shortcode. But thus the navigation looses its active state as my custom page is not the real category page.

Comment: Maybe the better approach would be to create a custom template for those specific categories. But actually I dont have a clue how to do that. Should be something like "taking the standard page layout and put it in there?".